# How to add a tab between to words

Tags: datastage

I have a requirement to add a tab between two words.  Can someone point me to a function that will accomplish this goal?

```
Input: Word1 Word2
output: word1 <inserted tab> word2
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
inLink.Word1 : Char(9) : inLink.Word2
```

I'd recommend pre-loading the value as the initial value of a stage variable, let's call it svTab, so the function only needs to be evaluated once.

```
inLink.Word1 : svTab : inLink.Word2
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know datastage but did you try `\t` ? Apparently it works for some other functions like [delim](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/8.5?topic=listing-delim-string)

Comment: stumbled upon a post that suggested simply concatenate char(9) in the transformer    word1:char(9):word2.  This worked.